# Make Icons clickable in OpenUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a requirement in which user can supply multiple icons in openUI5 header.

I am succuessfull in displaying that. However, when Icon's are clicked normal expand/collapse happens.

How can I stop it?

here is the code

```
sap.m.myaccordion.prototype._getImageControl = function(aCssClasses, oParent) {
var mProperties = {
    src : this.getIcon(),
    densityAware : this.getIconDensityAware()

};

this._oImageControl = sap.m.ImageHelper.getImageControl(null, this._oImageControl, oParent, mProperties, aCssClasses);

return this._oImageControl;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a working(not exactly :D) example.

I suppose you accordion is 'stealing' the click event and is acting on it. Check you expand/collapse handler and see which event is executing it. If the click area/target is the whole div encapsulating the icons your problem are not the icons :)
If so ... move this click event to a button for toggling the accordion.